# SubDocumentos Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sou iniciante em NoSQL.

Gostaria de registrar diversos Subdocumentos, referentes ao registro de transações financeiras em um documento.

**Minha duvida é: ****Suportaria um volume de 20.000 subdocumentos em um documento?**

existe algum limite, além do tamanho do documento?

existe outra forma melhor de registrar isso?

Fico preocupado com o numero de documentos em uma collection.

Em uma collection "Lancamentos" existem alguns documentos, 1 para cada empresa registrada.

Minha duvida é:
Quantos subdocumentos comportam um documento no mongodb?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Minha duvida é:
Quantos subdocumentos comportam um documento no mongodb?

ou esse não é exatamente um problema?

Comment: Veja se este link responde a sua dúvida https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/